# Output showing for every condition..what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program for school that has a hard coded array of elements, and the user must search for an element within the array. The output will then tell the user if the number is in the array or not by outputting a 0 or 1 (1 being yes 0 being no). However, the output I keep getting is for every element in the set and not just the number I am searching for. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
int l[10] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
int i;
int it;

cout<<"This program searches a list to find an item within that list"<<endl;
cout<<"1 is true ; 0 is false"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter a number between 1 and 20 to be searched: ";
cin>>it;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
if (it==l[i])
 cout<<"1"<<endl; 
else
 cout<<"0"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're printing `0` or `1` for every element in the array. That's why you are seeing the output like that. You're going to need a boolean flag that you check after the for loop finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing the basic idea behind a **loop**. In your code you loop thru your elements and check every one, and output `0` or `1` after **every** test. If you want to print the output once, store it in a bool value and print it **after** the loop ends.

You can also `break` from the loop when you find the element in it and output `0` only when no element is found (so when `i==arraySize`).

Answer (score 1):

So in this case the problem is that you are visiting each element in the array and printing whether or not they are what you are searching for. Instead you need to determine whether each of them are what you are searching for, then print. for example:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
  if (it==l[i]) {
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
cout<<"0"<<endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Pawels answer:

```
bool found = false;
//for loop add this
if(it == l[i])
    found = true;
//outside loop
if(found) //found it!
else //didnt find it
```